# set single value in object using node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of object which look like this:

```
let object = [
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`maths`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`science`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`IT`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`react`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`node`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`java`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`Asp.net`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`non-veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`Chinese`,
 }
]
```

Here `id` and `name` of some array are same but only difference is their `type`. Is there any possible way that, if I called `name` then I can get all the `type` of that `name`
For example:

```js
let object = [
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`maths`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`science`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`IT`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`react`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`node`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`java`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`Asp.net`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`non-veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`Chinese1`,
 }
];

object.map((value)=>{
console.log(value.name);
})
```

The problem is, that I am getting all the `names` multiple times. I want them to unique like this:

```
Subject
language
food
```

How can I use this single value to fetch the different `types` which are present inside my `Object`, so I can get values as:

```
expected = [
 { id:'01',
   name:'subject',
   type: {'maths','Science','IT'}
 },
 { id:'02',
   name:'language',
   type: {'react','node','java','Asp.net'}
 }
 { id:'03',
   name:'food',
   type: {'non-veg','veg','Chinese'}
 }
]
```

Comment: A basic way is to iterate over your existing array, look at the values and create the new one based on that. Basically "if element with .name exists, append to .type, otherwise create new .name element and append". Give this a try yourself, please. (questions about restructuring arrays are asked here on a daily basis, but no offense, this isn't a free code writing service)

Comment: expected output ```type``` should be array, right?

Comment: ye @ikhvjs it should be in object

Comment: @Vikas, invalid expected output format as type should not be in ```type:{'a','b','c'}```, you should use array to store the type: ```type:['a','b','c']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use `map` as `forEach` for iterating array, unless you want to create a new array (then you should return something).

You are looking for some kind of group by, in this cause you want to group by two field (`id` and `name`).

Here is how can it be done:

```js
const arr = [{id:`01`,name:`Subject`,type:`maths`},{id:`01`,name:`Subject`,type:`science`},{id:`01`,name:`Subject`,type:`IT`},{id:`02`,name:`language`,type:`react`},{id:`02`,name:`language`,type:`node`},{id:`02`,name:`language`,type:`java`},{id:`02`,name:`language`,type:`Asp.net`},{id:`03`,name:`food`,type:`non-veg`},{id:`03`,name:`food`,type:`veg`},{id:`03`,name:`food`,type:`Chinese1`}];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, e) => {
    const found = acc.find(x => x.id === e.id)
    found 
      ? found.type.push(e.type)
      : acc.push({ ...e, type: [e.type] })
    return acc
  }, [])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hey why declare `a` when its not in use

Comment: evn this also but this can be ignored `.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }`

Comment: Yes, this can be ignored. It's purpose is to prettify display of snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function

```
object.reduce((acc,i) => { 
                     let obj = acc.find(a => a?.id === i.id); 
                     i.type = obj ? [...obj.type, i.type] : [i.type];
                     if(!obj)
                        acc.push(i);
                     return acc;}, 
             []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple solution please check let me know if you need any other help

You can use complicated method like you can use reduce but this one is easy

```js
let object=
[
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`maths`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`science`,
 },
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`Subject`,
  type:`IT`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`react`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`node`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`java`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`language`,
  type:`Asp.net`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`non-veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`Chinese1`,
 }
];

let oldvalues;
object.map((value)=>{

if(oldvalues!=value.name){
oldvalues=value.name;
console.log(value.name);
}

})
```